# get data by parameter array php

Tags: php, arrays

get data by parameter array php?

my code is:

```
public function dataListAjax(Request $request)
{
    $os[] = $request->input('os');
    foreach ($os as $value) {
        $data = DataList::where('title', $value)->get();
       // return $data;
   }
   return $data;
```

}

this is my req : xxx.local/ajax-data?os=centos&os=ubuntu

why i only get data ubuntu? why not i get both data ubuntu and centos?

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Ubuntu","content":"ubuntu content","is_published":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

Comment: You have os in 2 places. The first os is being overwritten by ubuntu, the second variable definition. You are assigning both values in a single variable name.

Comment: why i cannot pass req like this: xxx.local/ajax-data?title%5B%5D=centos&title%5B%5D=ubuntu beacuse os is an array i am rirght

Comment: you can do os=centos&os1=ubuntu. os is a variable when you read it, it's not an array.

Comment: thanks unixmiah i will try that

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to process the querystring data that is "keyed" with `os` as an array, you only need to append `[]` after each `os`.

```
xxx.local/ajax-data?os[]=centos&os[]=ubuntu
```

and remove the `[]` from:

```
$os[] = $request->input('os');
// ^^-- this will push the os data as a subarray (you don't want that)
```

Then the `$os` array will look like this:

```
$os = array("centos", "ubuntus");
```

Comment: @Ade Is this issue fixed or does my suggestion not work as desired?  Please always endeavor to progress all of your questions to a system-recognized resolution.